# Dependabot generating PR’s daily even when I set trigger to manually

Tags: triggers, schedule, dependabot

I have created dependabot.yml file with schedule set to “weekly” and day set to “saturday”.
But when I merge the existing PR’s created by dependabot , it again creates a new one as soon as some of them are closed.
Does not waits for saturday.
Any help would be great

Comment: can you post your dependabot config setup?

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/37658